# Possibly unhandled CastError: Cast to date failed for value "function now() { [native code] } on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, express, mongoose

I'm getting the following error when running Express app

> Possibly unhandled CastError: Cast to date failed for value "function
>   now() { [native code] }

The date field is defined on model as:

```
updated: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
}
```

So, I'm logging the response and the field comes with this format

```
updated: Thu May 21 2015 16:21:32 GMT-0300 (ART)
```

Actually we've using **Mongoose v 3.4.0**

I've also tried to format the response with Moment.js but the warning still appears on the terminal.

I've would appreciate your help.

Comment: It sounds like somehow the _string_ `function now() { [native code] }` ended up in your database (or in a model instance), and Mongoose is trying to cast that string to a `Date` instance (and fails).

Comment: try `Date.now()`

Comment: Looks as if the documentation is wrong. I was also using Date.now, but as @ken suggested, it's Date.now()

Answer (score 2):

Old question but as mentioned by Ken, to create or update provide the Schema/Model with the Date value

`sendHelpDate: Date.now()`

This will save to the DB as `"sendHelpDate" : ISODate("2018-06-27T10:49:29.328+0000"),`
as opposed to passing the function of Date.now see below:

```
    message: 'Cast to Date failed for value "[Function: now]" at 
    path "sendHelpDate"',
    name: 'CastError',        
    stringValue: '"[Function: now]"',
    kind: 'Date',
    value: [Function: now],
    path: 'sendHelpDate',
    reason: [Object]                                                         
    _message: 'Bookings validation failed', 
    name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Hope the extra detail will help someone in future